# What does this QR code I found in Abstergo's office mean?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I found a QR code in Abstergo's office, but I don't know what it means. It just decodes to a bunch of numbers: `12491839`.

What is the QR code for?

Comment: Is this QR code on a blue sticky note?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are QR codes around the office on sticky notes which you can interact with by pressing the appropriate interact button. You will notice your tablet thing in the lower left will light up its interact icon when you are close to and pointed at a sticky note. When collecting one it will give you some in game information which I assume the QR code is meant to refer to.

I don't think they have any further use than this.

Comment: I was dumb enough to scan them with my actual tablet instead of the ingame one.

Comment: I spent a while trying to do that as well. Fortunately for me my phone wouldn't scan it so I started wondering if it was less easter egg and more part of the game. :)

Comment: @Flater I did the same thing! That's how I found the numbers it decodes to

Answer (score 1):

Scanned it with my qr reader and it came up as "Secret Note" nothing more.